# Range of char type values in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to store more than a byte value to a char type?

Say for example `char c;` and I want to store 1000 in `c`. is it possible to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to use `char`, anyway?  `short int` will give you 2 bytes, and you're not going to easily store 1000 in smaller space.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, no, you can't store more than a byte value to a `char` type. In C, a `char` and a byte are the same size, but not necessarily limited to 8 bits. Many standards bodies tend to use the term "octet" for an exactly-8-bit value.

If you look inside `limits.h` (from memory), you'll see the `CHAR_BIT` symbol (among others) telling you how many bits are actually used for a `char` and, if this is large enough then, yes, it *can* store the value 1000.

Comment: On virtually all desktops, however, chars are exactly 8 bits large, and accounting for the possibility of unusual byte size in your code is probably overkill.

Comment: @user168715 : Some of us work in larger universes than the set of virtually all desktops :-)

Comment: @user168715: I think it's a question of how much effort it will be to support it. If it's just a matter of typing `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`, I do it. If supporting bytes of a different size will actually be significant wasted effort, I assert somehow (perhaps just in documentation) that CHAR_BIT must be 8 and get on with my life.

Comment: POSIX and Windows (which account for basically everything except DSPs; even most embedded systems these days) require `CHAR_BIT==8`, as does any remotely portable way of communicating with the outside world and the internet, so I see really little value to supporting non-octet byte sizes.

Comment: @Amigable, my "no" answer was to the question "is it possible to store more than a byte value to a char type". I'll clarify. @R, I'l be pedantic here and state the "C" generally means ISO rather than POSIX but your point is well taken. The _vast_ majority of systems have an 8-bit char type.

Comment: @paxdiablo, the *vast* mindbogglingly huge majority of systems have an 8-bit char type. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The range of values you can store in a C type depends on its size, and that is not specified by C, it depends on the architecture. A `char` type has a minimum of 8 bits. And typically (almost universally) that's also its maximum (you can check it in your  `limits.h`). 
Hence, in  a char you will be able to store from -128 to 127, or from 0 to 255 (signed or unsigned).

Answer (score 3):

The minimum size for a `char` in C is 8 bits, which is not wide enough to hold more than 256 values.  It *may* be wider in a particular implementation such as a word-addressable architecture, but you shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: +1 for recalling that there are such things as word-addressable architectures :-)

Answer (score 2):

Include [`limits.h`](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?limits.h+3) and check the value of `CHAR_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. The C standard requires that a `char` can hold at least 8 bits, so you can't depend on being able to store a value longer than 8 bits in a `char` portably.

(* In most commonly-used systems today, chars are 8 bits).

Answer (score 0):

Char's width is system-dependent. But assuming you're using something reasonably C99-compatible, you should have access to a header stdint.h, which defines types of the formats intN_t and uintN_t where N=8,16,32,64. These are guaranteed to be at least N bits wide. So if you want to be certain to have a type with a certain amount of bits (regardless of system), those are the guys you want.

Example:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t foo; /* Unsigned, 32 bits */
int16_t bar;  /* Signed, 16 bits */
```

Comment: You should keep in mind that those types are only required if the implementation has types that meets the specs for them (which is, admittedly, pretty likely). For example, if there is no 8-bit type, `uint8_t` won't exist. And if they do exist, they are guaranteed to be _exactly_ N bits wide, not "at least". The "at least" types are `int_leastN_t`. If you fix that, I'll give you an uplift :-)